# how to use continue within complition blocks

Tags: ios, block

when I am using continue in for in loop its works fine but when I am using it like this

```
for (SomeClass * clss in response.items){
 [self.service executeQuery: e2uRelationshipQuery completionHandler: ^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket,  SomeOtherClass *response, NSError *error) {

   continue;
   }];
 }
```

now in this case it encounter an error saying  'continue' statement not in loop statement

```
for (SomeClass * clss in response.items){

   continue;

 }
```

but when I use it without completion  block it works fine
so is there any other method to use continue in completion block 
or We can't use continue inside blocks.?

Comment: Is this particular block asynchronous?

Comment: It is illegal for a syntax. you have to use `continue` keyword directly in a loop statement.

Comment: I believe you can just replace `continue` with `return`.

Comment: but return will return from the function it will not go to loop

Comment: @Lyndsey Scott its a completion block

Comment: @FaranGhani Some completion blocks are synchronous and some are asynchronous. If it's asynchronous though, what you're trying to do wouldn't make sense since the block may not complete before the next iteration of the loop. It's it's synchronous though, there might be some "cheats" to achieve what you're going for.

Comment: @ Lyndsey Scott its synchronous block.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't.
If you need to do nothing when you encounter some values of the params inside the block, just do nothing.